# python: bot telegram с аргументами

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, telegram

Мне нужна команда, где будет писаться аргумент, т.е. команда: `Отдать [id] [integer]`.

Допустим, пользователь вводит команду `Отдать 1234567890 50000`.

В файле, где находятся всё `user_id` зарегистрированных пользоватлей, идет поиск того самого ИД (1234567890).

Если его нет, то `send_message(такого пользователя нет)`.

Если есть, то `send_message(вы отдали игроку 50000!)`.

Я новичок и мне нужно направление, как это вообще воплотить и какая библиотека мне поможет. Я не прошу за меня писать код, просто нужно понять примерный алгоритм, заранее всем спасибо!

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону `aiogram`

Comment: Чтобы использовать *aiogram* мне нужно будет все команды менять, это будет непросто. Есть варианты связаны с библиотекой *pyTelegramBotApi*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я не совсем понял вопроса, но не проще было бы написать сперва случайную команду с префиксом `'/'` и к примеру полностью: `'/give'` затем обрабатывать любой текст пользователя через текстовый обработчик, а как именно обрабатывать? Сперва проверять текст, что он начинается на `'/give'` то есть: `if message.text.startswith('/give')` затем следующая проверка, которая разобьёт весь отправленный текст пользователя на три части через пробел, а то есть команду, затем айди пользователя, которому должна будет выдаться определенная сумма, после сама уже сумма и это дело сделать, просто через `'split(' ')'`, если разбить текст через сплит не удастся произойдет ошибка, которую и можно обрабатывать в качестве, того решил ли пользователь побаловаться введя команду без аргументов или действительно выполнить какое-либо действие, если ошибки через сплит не будет наблюдаться затем можно написать проверку пользователя в базе которому должна будет даться какая-то сумма и вообще дальше ты можешь ограничься только фантазией.